# Xcode 14 Cannot see Custom iOS application target properties

Tags: ios, xcode

When I am creating a new project in Xcode with target iOS, in the Target -> Info tab it's not showing "Custom iOS application target properties", Instead it's showing "Custom MacOS application target properties".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fixed by changing `Target -> Build Settings -> Base SDK -> iOS`

Comment: confirm this works!

Answer (score 0):

The project you should create or open is a macOS project, please create an iOS project xcode menu "file->New->project-iOS project"